# How can I get Excel VBA to pull through specific data in a field when specific column has an answer YES

Tags: excel, vba

I am Using Excel 2003 and I amd trying to pull through specific data from a worksheet.  What I would like is when there is yes populated under a column with a specific name it will pull through the whole row of data if the answer is yes.  Here is some VBA code I have created.  I have The worksheet Inventory has all the data, would like data to pull through to Reports worksheet. Any help would be greatfuly received.

```
Sub AnalyseEMPHInfo()
Dim rngReports As Range
Dim rngInventory As Range
Dim StrSchemeNumber As String
Dim StrUnitName As String
Dim StrTCsSigned As String
Dim strVetSurveyCompleted As String
Dim StrBiosecurityReceived As String
Dim StrCDSurveyReceived As String
Dim strBPHSOptInOut As String

Set rngReports = Worksheets("Reports").Range("A2")
Set rngInventory = Worksheets("Inventory").Range("A2")
Do Until rngInventory = ""
    With rngInventory
        If .Offset(0, 1).Value = StrSchemeNumber And .Offset(0, 2).Value = StrUnitName _
            And .Offset(0, 3) = StrTCsSigned And .Offset(0, 4) = strVetSurveyCompleted _
            And .Offset(0, 5) = StrBiosecurityReceived _
            And .Offset(0, 6) = StrCDSurveyReceived _
            And .Offset(0, 7) = strBPHSOptInOut Then


    End With
    Set rngInventory = rngInventory.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through all the values in column A starting with A2 and check column D for a 'Yes'.  If found, it will copy the whole row to the Reports sheet

```
Sub AnalyseEMPHInfo()
    Dim rNext As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rngInventory As Range

    With Worksheets("Inventory")
        Set rngInventory = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    End With

    For Each rCell In rngInventory.Cells
        If UCase(rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value) = "YES" Then 'check column D
            With Worksheets("Reports")
                Set rNext = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End With

            rCell.EntireRow.Copy rNext
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```